# Помогите найти портфолио плагин на wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wp-plugin

пытаюсь найти рабочий плагин на wordpress.
Плагин должен иметь кнопку "загрузить еще", контент - изображения, ну и само собой настраиваемая сетка.

Перепробовал кучу плагинов, у одних проблемы с мобильной версией, у других не хватает функционала. Буду рад любому совету

PS Вроде неплохо работает стандартный Media Grid, но там убогий лайтбокс, который на моб отображается в маленьком окошке, может его как-то можно поменять?

Comment: [пользуюсь этим](https://codecanyon.net/item/the-grid-responsive-wordpress-grid-plugin/13306812?ref=athemez) - мне отлично подходит под все нужды

Comment: @Nilsan спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Неплохим вариантом считаю плагин `Media Grid - Wordpress Responsive Portfolio` от LCweb на CodeCanyon.